# Why Visual Studio 2010 Form not show any text after power failure?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am building stand alone desktop application, In development process my desktop computer is turned off due to power failure. After sometime when power is come I face a problem in which all text in form is not visible and in data gridview control show divide by zero exception some like below image:

[image: Screen Shot of problem]

Please Resolve my issue.

Comment: Clean the soulution and rebuild it.

Comment: Right click on the tab -> Close all documents -> Rebuild & Clean solution like marko mentioned

Comment: Rebuild & Clean solution not worked...

Comment: Is there a datasource for the dgv set in the properties?

Comment: datasource is not set for dgv

Answer (score 0):

check the database is running if you are using, or try to rebuilt after close all windows

Comment: My database works perfectly and also try to rebuilt but it not works.